# Calculate ratio between 2 rows in PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like

| groupid | numofproducts | matches |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | false |
| 1 | 1 | true |
| 2 | 1 | true |
| 2 | 1 | false |

and need to calculate a simple ratio along the lines of

> for a group, calculate the ratio of matches to the total set of products

so for group 1 the ratio would be 1/6, or 16.67%, group 2 would be 1/2 or 50%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to get the result you want. For example

```
select
  groupid,
  1.0 * sum(case when matches then numofproducts else 0 end) /
  sum(numofproducts) as ratio 
from t
group by groupid
order by groupid
```

Result:

```
 groupid  ratio                  
 -------- ---------------------- 
 1        0.16666666666666666667 
 2        0.50000000000000000000
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bLnpS9a2vHztYGtFDK9uwr/0).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the  [FILTER  clause of  count](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-expressions.html)  function clause to count only those where matches is true and use `sum` sunction to get the total num_of_products. From there is just a simple math operation. So:

```
with test (groupid, numofproducts,  matches) as
     (values (1, 5, false)
           , (1, 1, true)
           , (2, 1, true)
           , (2, 1, false)
     )
-- your query starts here
select groupid, round( ( 100.0*count(*) filter (where matches)/sum(numofproducts)),2)  pct_matches
  from test
 group by groupid;
```

Comment: I like the filter clause, considering it's part of the SQL Standard. +1 for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with conditional aggregation with `SUM(`) aggregate function if you use a `FILTER` clause:

```
SELECT groupid,
       ROUND(100.0 * SUM(numofproducts) FILTER (WHERE matches) / SUM(numofproducts), 2) ratio
FROM tablename
GROUP BY groupid
ORDER BY groupid;
```

I assume that the data type of the column `matches` is `BOOLEAN`.
If it is `VARCHAR` then change the `WHERE` clause to: `WHERE matches = 'true'`.

If there is a case that there are not any `true` values in the column `matches` for a `groupid` then you should also use `COALESCE()` to get `0` instead of `null` as result:

```
SELECT groupid,
       ROUND(100.0 * COALESCE(SUM(numofproducts) FILTER (WHERE matches), 0) / SUM(numofproducts), 2) ratio
FROM tablename
GROUP BY groupid
ORDER BY groupid;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=770862f1406068ba251c10ae7acf297f).